# React Hooks -Redux Saga Middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am creating a React application with Saga middleware. And I have few doubts to clarify.

- On the first mount, why is it we are destructing an unknown prop  `const { onGetPhonesAndTablets } = props` which is not passed from the Redux Store (State Container).
- Why is it required to `setPhoneAndTabletsList(phonesAndTablets)` before dispatching an action `onGetPhonesAndTablets` . As the prop `phonesAndTablets` will have its value after dispatching an action i.e., `onGetPhonesAndTablets`

```
const Home = props => {
  
  const { 
    phonesAndTablets
  } = props
  
  const [phonesAndTabletsList, setPhoneAndTabletsList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { 
      onGetPhonesAndTablets
    } = props
    setPhoneAndTabletsList(phonesAndTablets)
    onGetPhonesAndTablets()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(phonesAndTablets)) setPhoneAndTabletsList(phonesAndTablets)
  }, [phonesAndTablets])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <ProductCategoryList list={phonesAndTabletsList}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

Home.propTypes = {
  phonesAndTablets: PropTypes.array,
  onGetPhonesAndTablets : PropTypes.func
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ home }) => ({
  phonesAndTablets: home.phonesAndTablets
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onGetPhonesAndTablets: () => dispatch(getPhoneAndTablets())
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why this app uses a local state to store the redux state, which is passed as a prop. Seems redundant, not to mention bad for performance.

There is a selector hook, which lets components access individual pieces of redux state. `useSelector(state => state.home.phonesAndTablets)`.

> You can also pass a second argument, `shallowEqual`, which makes the
> comparison function do a value comparison, as opposed to reference
> comparison. This avoids unnecessary re-renders due to objects/arrays
> whose contents are equal, but whose references point to different
> objects. Remember that `['a'] !== ['a']` in JS.

There is also a dispatch hook to do the same for actions. `useDispatch()`. Then you can do

```js
const list = useSelector(state => state.home.phonesAndTablets, shallowEqual)
const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPhoneAndTablets())
}, [])

return (
  <>
      <ProductCategoryList list={list ?? []} />
  </>
)
```

I would personally add a check if the list is empty before fetching a new list, but maybe the app is supposed to fetch a new list whenever `Home` is mounted. I have no idea.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I have now a simplified version. Thanks for the redundant thing. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the above code seems redundant as the state is already managed and handled by the State Container (Redux Store). So I tried removing redundant codes.

Personally I prefer `mapStateToProps` to `selectors`.

```
const Home = props => {
  
  const { 
    phonesAndTablets, 
    onGetPhonesAndTablets
  } = props

  useEffect(() => {
    onGetPhonesAndTablets()
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <ProductCategoryList list={phonesAndTablets ? phonesAndTablets : ''}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

Home.propTypes = {
  phonesAndTablets: PropTypes.array,
  onGetPhonesAndTablets : PropTypes.func
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ home }) => ({
  phonesAndTablets: home.phonesAndTablets
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onGetPhonesAndTablets: () => dispatch(getPhoneAndTablets())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```